# What is internally happening which does not let me print output ? last line of csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to fetch last record of csv file using below code.

Nothing gets printed as an output.

I have 101 records in csv file. Need to fetch last record of file

**Code :**

```
import csv

count = 0
with open('/folder/emp.csv','r') as csvdt:

  csv_rd = csv.reader(csvdt)
  get_record_count  = len(list(csv_rd)) #101

  for j in  csv_rd:
    if count == get_record_count:
      print(j)
    else:
      count = count + 1
```

What is internally happening which does not let me print output ?

Comment: Maybe the `count` never reaches 101. Loop ends before it. Try printing count in every iteration to see it's max value and what happens when it reaches 101.

Comment: I think `csv_rd` is a generator and you exhausted it at the line including `len(list(csv_rd))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv_rd` is a generator, so you exhaust the content of `csv_rd` if you apply `len(list(csv_rd))`. In order to prevent exhaustion, you have to get the list of `csv_rd` first.

### Code:

```py
import csv

with open('/folder/emp.csv','r') as csvdt:

    csv_rd = csv.reader(csvdt)

    lines = list(csv_rd)
    get_record_count = len(lines) #101

    for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
        if i == get_record_count:
            print(line)
```

If what you want to do is only getting the last line, the following code might be usefull as well.

```py
import csv

with open('/folder/emp.csv','r') as csvdt:
    csv_rd = csv.reader(csvdt)
    last_line = list(csv_rd)[-1]
    print(last_line)
```

Comment: : can you tell me what is the meaning of exhaustion

Comment: Sure. `csv_rd` contained information of the 101 lines at first. Once you called `list(len(csv_rd))`, all the lines were consumed.
You can confirm this by a toy example `g = (i for i in range(3)); print(len(list(g))); print(len(list(g)))`. The first `print(len(list(g)))` shows `3`, whereas the second `print(len(list(g)))` shows `0` because of the exhaustion.

Comment: I think this post might be helpful to understand the generator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do/231855#231855

Comment: When you read something from a file or stream once, you can't read the same thing again (unless the thing you're reading from allows you to explicitly rewind, or gives you the same contents if you close and open it again, which you can do with a file, but not e.g. with a network connection).

Comment: @quasi-human  : How you are able to debug this from my code.